# Wait For Dispatch Action to be completed outside the component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a screen that user will choose a type of Quiz from, then quiz questions should be generated, currentGameInformation should be updated in the store and then new screen should be visible.

Since dispatch actions are async, sometimes the currentGameInformation is not updated, so my app crashes when it gets to next page. I want it to wait until it goes to next page so the information is available.

On Press of a button, a function is called in my component called startTheGame()

```
//inside the screen component 
startTheGame = async (id) => {
    let navigation = this.props.navigation;
    await StartTheGame(MASTER_TIME_PERIOD, {time_period_id: id}).then(function(){
        console.log("Navigating");
        navigation.replace('Quiz');
    });

};


//This function is located outside the component,
//It is a library that handles all the Quiz functionalities
export async function StartTheGame(type, details) {
let state = store.getState();
let username = state.currentUser.username;
if(username === undefined){
   //AWS gets the current user working fine and waiting to be completed
   let user = await GetCurrentUserAWS(); 
   username = user.username;
}
//set game status to loading
let currentGameInfo = {};

let currentDayPoints = await GetCurrentDayPointsForUserDB(username); 

//Redux Thunk function (is sent, but not waiting to get done) 
SetCurrentDayPoints(currentDayPoints); 
//redux thunk function (is set but not waiting for it to be done) 
SetGameStatus(SET_GAME_START_LOADING, QUIZ_GAME_START_STATUS_LOADING); 
//at this point, current day points are either updated/not and same with game status

let questions = await GenerateQuestions(type, details).catch(err => {
    SetGameStatus(SET_GAME_START_ERROR, QUIZ_GAME_START_STATUS_ERROR); //same not waiting to be completed
});

currentGameInfo = {
    questions: questions,
    points: 0,
    questionIndexesAnsweredCorrectly: [],
    questionIndexesAnsweredIncorrectly: [],
    shouldRestartBeEnabled: false,
    currIndex:0,
    questionsAnsweredInRow:0,
    gameType:type
};
SetGameStatusSuccess(currentGameInfo); //same not waiting 
return currentGameInfo; }
```

My goal is to return only after SetGameStatusSuccess has been completed

```
export function SetGameStatusSuccess(currentGameInfo){
return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({type: SET_GAME_START_SUCCESS, payload:{
            gameStatus:QUIZ_GAME_START_STATUS_STARTED,
            currentGameInformation:currentGameInfo
    }});
}; }

export function SetGameStatus(gameStatus, quizStatus){
return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({type: gameStatus, payload:{gameStatus:quizStatus}});
};}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do this without the need of mapDispatchToProps function ?

Comment: I found one way with which I am waiting on the component side for the props to change and then I would navigate to the page that needs this information. but if there is way to find out when dispatching an action is completely finished without using component that would be great to know!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` your `SetGameStatus` function call. Since your `StartTheGame` function is marked as async, all you need to do is:

```
let currentDayPoints = await GetCurrentDayPointsForUserDB(username); 
SetCurrentDayPoints(currentDayPoints); 
//add 'await' here
await SetGameStatus(SET_GAME_START_LOADING, QUIZ_GAME_START_STATUS_LOADING);
```

and same for here:

```
let questions = await GenerateQuestions(type, details).catch(asybc (err) => {
    await SetGameStatus(SET_GAME_START_ERROR, QUIZ_GAME_START_STATUS_ERROR);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, that is not working, I have tried it. I think it might not be working because SetGameStatusSuccess is not really async by type. Also, I am not awaiting anything there. I will update my code to include SetGameStatusSuccess as well. Let me know if you might have any other suggestions, or general advice if I should be changing my logic completely.